# Backgroundworker doesn't work... VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, backgroundworker

this is my code:

```
    Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    For i = 0 To 1000
        Dim inum As String = i & "0"


        Dim request As System.Net.HttpWebRequest = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.google.nl/search?q=site:" & combobox1.Text & "&hl=nl&start=" & inum)
        Dim response As System.Net.HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse

        Dim sr As System.IO.StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())

        Dim sourcecode As String = sr.ReadToEnd
        Dim search As String = combobox1.Text
        Dim r As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("http://" & search & "/\w*")
        Dim matches As MatchCollection = r.Matches(sourcecode)


        For Each itemcode As Match In matches

            Dim item As String = (itemcode.ToString.Split("""").GetValue(0))
            Dim url As New Net.WebClient
            Dim str As String = url.DownloadString("http://www.prcheck.nl/results.php?url=" & item)

            If str.Contains(">0/10") Then
                ListBox1.Items.Add("(0/10) " & item)
            ElseIf str.Contains("1/10") Then
                ListBox1.Items.Add("(1/10) " & item)
            ElseIf str.Contains("2/10") Then
                ListBox1.Items.Add("(2/10) " & item)
            ElseIf str.Contains("3/10") Then
                ListBox1.Items.Add("(3/10) " & item)
            ElseIf str.Contains("4/10") Then
                ListBox1.Items.Add("(4/10) " & item)
            ElseIf str.Contains("5/10") Then
                ListBox1.Items.Add("(5/10) " & item)
            ElseIf str.Contains("6/10") Then
                ListBox1.Items.Add("(6/10) " & item)
            ElseIf str.Contains("7/10") Then
                ListBox1.Items.Add("(7/10) " & item)
            ElseIf str.Contains("8/10") Then
                ListBox1.Items.Add("(8/10) " & item)
            ElseIf str.Contains("9/10") Then
                ListBox1.Items.Add("(9/10) " & item)
            ElseIf str.Contains("10/10") Then
                ListBox1.Items.Add("(10/10) " & item)
            Else
                ListBox1.Items.Add("(0/10) " & item)

            End If

            Label2.Text = ListBox1.Items.Count
        Next



        If Not sourcecode.Contains("<b>Volgende</b>") Then
            MsgBox("")
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

and combobox1.text = www.google.nl ( example )

at button 1 the code is:

```
BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
```

and if backgroundworker is done:

```
    Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
    MsgBox("Done")
End Sub
```

if i click button 1, i get within a half second the message: Done

what's wrong with the code??

if i put the code inside backgroundworker1 just in button1 it works but goes really slow..

Comment: Debug + Exceptions, tick the thrown box for CLR exceptions.  Be sure to read the MSDN Library docs on what you can do inside DoWork.  Updating a ListBox is not one of them.

Comment: if i use try catch ex as exception msgbox(ex...) end try i don't get an error. can you tell me where i can tick that box?

Comment: I did at progress completed this code: if e.error isnot nothing then msgbox with the error. well i got this error: Error: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'combobox1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

Answer (score 3):

You can only update the UI from within the main application thread, in this case you're attempting to do it via a background thread that has been created by the background worker which will throw an exception as you've found.

What you'll need to do it run the code which adds to the ListBox on the main thread which you can do via [BeginInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a06c0dc2.aspx) and a custom delegate which takes the item you want to add as a parameter, the delegate can then add the item to list box - there's an example of how to do this in the docs for BeginInvoke.

Comment: but what i don't understand, the error has nothing to do with the listbox has it?? the error is for the combobox...

Answer (score 0):

I would return a list or array of items to be added from the background worker and then fill the ListBox in the RunWorkerCompleted event handler.